# Complex Javascript Regexp Expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to test the content of a particular text field for the following rules:

1. It should be number with 5 digits and a caret symbol at the end of each number.
2. The above can occur only 4 times and the entire content should always end with number.

Examples:

Valid

- 11111^11111
- 11111

Invalid

- 11111^11111^1111
- 11111^11111^11111^11111^11111
- 11111^11111^11111^11111^
- 11111^

I am trying to implement the same using regex, and tried:

```
/^([0-9]{5}\^){1,4}$/g
```

Comment: Your question is confusing.  You list invalid groups as valid.  Which do you want?

Answer (score 5):

Try the following:

```
/^\d{5}(\^\d{5}){0,3}$/
```

It matches 5 digits at the beginning of the line `^\d{5}`, followed by zero to three `{0,3}` groups of a caret and 5 digits `(\^\d{5})`, thus guaranteeing that you can only have  4 groups.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2KMeS/)**.

Comment: More than one group is supposed to be invalid, by the question.

Comment: @Daedalus: His first test has two groups and it's valid: `11111^11111(valid)`.

Comment: As of this writing, your regex would match the invalid groups as well.  See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/TqyL4/).

Comment: @Daedalus: Indeed, it should be three groups instead of four. I've edited my answer, thanks

Comment: That isn't precisely what I meant.   See my comment on the question for what I'm talking about.

Comment: @Daedalus: I admit the question is a bit confusing, but I think based on OP's examples and his intro, he basically wants to match groups of 5 digits separated by a caret, and up to 4 groups. This interpretation, I think, reflects the introduction as well as the examples and my regex.

Comment: @BharathKumar: You're welcome. Feel free to mark the answer as accepted by clicking the tick on the left.